# Spring execute a method in all the controllers methods without injecting the service

Tags: java, spring

I have an external IAM service (provides authentication and authorization features) which I would like to use to authenticate user requests.

I will ignore the code in below examples as it is not relevant.

In my **IAMServiceImpl** I have the `authenticate(String token)` method, which will validate the token.

I would like to reuse this method in all the controller methods, but I would like to avoid injecting the **IAMServiceImpl** in all the controllers.

**Question:** How can I register this method to be called at the beginning of each controller method, without injecting the service in all the controllers.

**NOTE** I have to pass the token to the service, which I will get from request headers.

Thank you!

Comment: you should use filters for authentication and authorization all the controller methods

Comment: I am using external authentication server, called through rest

Answer (score 1):

You should use Aspect Oriented Programming, it is good solution for your use case.

Have a look at Spring's documentation for AOP, specifically @Before advice.

> https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways (might be more):

1) [Spring AOP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm): You can setup an advice to be executed before controller gets called in.

2) [Filter chain](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter) (more suitable for your use-case): Spring security has a set of filters that can be used to provide authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use **Shiro** or **Spring Security** to help you achieve these like filters, or you could use **Aspect Oriented Programming** before each Controller.